# Finding cause of orphaned database connections between tomcat with hikari pool and PostgreSQL server

Tags: spring, postgresql, tomcat, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I have many unclosed connections between my tomcat server and the postgresql server. I'm using a hikari pool to manage the connections.
I know that I can configure hikari to take care of orphaned connections and also postgres is able to close them after a certain configurable time of beeing idle.
But all this is only good to work agains the symptoms instead of solving the actual problem.

An idea I had was to create a memory dump from tomcat and to follow the PgConnection classes to Spring, Tomcat until I find the right DataAccessObject. But the amount of classes and layers that are involved because of tomcat, spring, hikari is huge.

Question: Is it possible to analyze the stack trace from our business code to the open PgConnection objects in MAT for example and to search for a pattern? For example: "Follow the references from PgConnection until you find a class where the package name starts with "com.blabla.dao.MyDAO".

Or do you have a better idea how to achive this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you using PGBouncer?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure hikari to detect and log connection leaks by setting `leakDetectionThreshold` property. The value is in milliseconds and should be set to a reasonable number to not trigger false positives.

The other option is to configure how long an idle can stay. Note, that a DB connection is a valid state, as you use connection pool. By default hikari will keep all configured connections alive. This can be changed with `minimumIdle` property.

See: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#configuration-knobs-baby

Comment: Yes, minimumIdle is set to 8 and those 8 should stay connected. But when I run integration test (one test at the time, sequentially) the idle connections are growing and growing over 100 connections altough there is only one "interaction" happeing that the same time. The 8 idle connections should be more than enough for those tests to run. I will try leakDetectionThreshold.